# Why can't I access the object I created on the heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I'm trying to learn C++ and one thing is not clear to me. I know that the `new`  operator creates an object on the free store, so if an object within a block is created with new, it won't be destroyed after the scope ends. But in the following example I cannot access the object allocated by new after the block. What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    {double *d=new double{4};}
   
    std::cout<<*d;
}
```

Comment: The pointer `d` itself no longer exists outside the block.  The `double` it used to point to has not been destroyed, but you no longer have any record of where it is.

Comment: The statement `std::cout<<*d;` should be generating compilation errors because the `d` variable is only defined inside the statement block and `std::cout` is outside the statement block.

Comment: Your code [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a83260984fd98290), what's unclear for you about that error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new object *isn't* destroyed. But the only pointer to it is gone, because *it* is destroyed (which does nothing to what it points to, aside from deny you access to it).

You can see how the allocation survives the block by declaring the pointer *outside* the block, while still performing allocation within it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    double *d;

    {d=new double{4};}
   
    std::cout<<*d;
}
```